# Creating a line animation on canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm a newbie in canvas drawing. I want to draw the PV string model and the direction of flow of electrons into `<canvas>` tag.

This is what I want to achieve, redrawing the lines from the following direction:

[image]

How do I initially set the animation location, and do I need to update it via `setTimeout`?

Here is what I try so far:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

if (canvas.getContext) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // drawing code here

  /* First Row */
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(2,150,224, 1)";
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(2,150,224, 1)";
  ctx.fillRect(110, 50, 50, 50);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(188,12,50, 1)";
  ctx.fillRect(170, 50, 50, 50);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(2,150,224, 1)";
  ctx.fillRect(230, 50, 50, 50);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(2,150,224, 1)";
  ctx.fillRect(290, 50, 50, 50);

  /* Second Row */
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,106,160, 1)";
  ctx.fillRect(50, 150, 50, 50);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,106,160, 1)";
  ctx.fillRect(110, 150, 50, 50);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,106,160, 1)";
  ctx.fillRect(170, 150, 50, 50);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,106,160, 1)";
  ctx.fillRect(230, 150, 50, 50);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,106,160, 1)";
  ctx.fillRect(290, 150, 50, 50);

  /* Paths */
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "3";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(34,177,76, 1)";
  ctx.moveTo(0, 75);
  ctx.lineTo(400, 75);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "10";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(34,177,76, 1)";
  ctx.moveTo(400, 75);
  ctx.lineTo(400, 175);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "3";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(34,177,76, 1)";
  ctx.moveTo(0, 175);
  ctx.lineTo(400, 175);
  ctx.stroke();


} else {
  // canvas-unsupported code here
}
```

```css
/* canvas {
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
} */
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve. You want to draw animating red arrows following the path of the green bars?

Comment: @ggorlen I wanna redraw an animate path on the current `ctx.beginPath()`.

Comment: So you want the three green lines to appear undrawn at the beginning, then gradually draw themselves starting from top left, moving first to top right, then to bottom right, then to bottom left over the course of a few seconds? And there are no red arrows involved?

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, that’s exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to animate this; here's my approach (excerpt; see 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ac0423r7/63/) for full code):

```
var lerp = (a, b, t) => a + t * (b - a);
var speed = 0.01;
var time = 0;
var visited = [];
var points = [
  {
    from: { x: 0, y: 75 },
    to: { x: 395, y: 75 }
  },
  {
    from: { x: 395, y: 75 },
    to: { x: 395, y: 175 }
  },
  {
    from: { x: 395, y: 175 },
    to: { x: 0, y: 175 }
  }
];

/* Paths */
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(34, 177, 76, 1)";

(function update() {
  if (points.length) {
    visited.push({
        x: lerp(points[0].from.x, points[0].to.x, time),
        y: lerp(points[0].from.y, points[0].to.y, time)
    });

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawBoxes(ctx);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(visited[0].x, visited[0].y)
    visited.forEach(e => ctx.lineTo(e.x, e.y));
    ctx.stroke();

    time += speed;

    if (time >= 1) {
        time = 0;
        points.shift();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }
})();
```

The idea is to keep a data structure of all the turning points, then [lerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) along the path, drawing a line along the way. Use an [easing](https://easings.net/) function instead of lerp if you prefer a more "modern"-looking animation; easing is usually easier to implement and may result in removal of some code (for example, no need to keep track of starting points and time).

Last minor note--your original code was cutting off the line at the right edge of the canvas, so I took the liberty of using 395 instead of 400 for the drawing width.